# Is $‖xy‖_{l_1}\geq\sum_k x_ky_k$ true?

Tags: real-analysis

Proof idea:

Given $l_1=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,...): \sum_{k}|x_k|<\infty\}$

Then $‖xy‖_{l_1} = (x,y)_{l_1}=\sum_k |x_ky_k|\geq\sum_k x_ky_k$.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: You should show us your work. Have you tried anything?

Comment: The one line proof is my work. I will mark it as such to be clearer.